# azure msal-brower with nextJs: passing only one scope to the API

Tags: reactjs, azure, next.js, msal-react

I've got a SPA calling an API. The user authenticates using Azure AD and I'm exposing the API with a custom scope (access).

I report below the responses based on different scopes:

- scopes = ['access'] => Authorised. Scope in the passed token is: "access"
- scopes = ['user.read'] => Not authorised. Scope in the passed token is: "openid profile User.Read email"
- scopes = ['access', 'user.read'] => Authorised. Scope in the passed token is: "access"
- scopes = ['user.read', 'access'] => Not authorised. Scope in the passed token is: "openid profile User.Read email"
- scopes = ['profile', 'email', 'openid', 'access'] => Authorised. Scope in the passed token is: "access"

I don't think it's normal behaviour because I couldn't find any reference around it. What if I need, in the API, the info coming from the User.Read as well?

Dep version: "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.26.0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same results.***

When I passed **['access', 'user.read']** ,I got token for only `access` scope like below:

[image]

Please check the **`aud`** (audience) claim of the token you are generating.

- If you are giving **`access`** as your scope, your **`aud`**  will be *api://your_app_id*.
- If you are giving **`user.read`** as your scope, your **`aud`**  will be *00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000* that means *graph.microsoft.com*.

If you are giving 2 different scopes like **['access', 'user.read']**, it will only consider first scope and generate token for that specific audience like below:

[image]

As mentioned by **Juunas** in this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63611993/access-token-with-azure-ad-api-scopes-and-graph-scops-does-not-authenticate-on-m), access token is valid for **one API only** based on the audience.

If you want the info coming from the **`User.Read`**, you need to generate two tokens, one for your API scope (access) and another for Graph API scope (user.read).

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[azure - Passing multiple scope values to Oauth token endpoint - by **Hari Krishna**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677157/passing-multiple-scope-values-to-oauth-token-endpoint)