# AuthenticationFailed when authenticating via nodejs app and package @azure/msal-node

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an Azure app registered . I am trying to authenticate to that app . I am able to do that and successfully get the accesstoken and idtoken.
However, when I use that token and try to make a request to list subscriptions API (https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01) , the request fails and give response "AuthenticationFailed". I have also tried changing the scope to `https://management.azure.com/.default` but the same error is there. Below is the nodejs code and I am also attaching the API permissions of app

[image]

```
const config = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'xxx',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations',
    clientSecret: 'yyy',
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
        console.log(message);
      },
      piiLoggingEnabled: false,
      logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
    },
  },
};

// Create msal application object
const pca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

// Create Express App and Routes
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const authCodeUrlParameters = {
    scopes: ['user.read','https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation'],
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
  };

  // get url to sign user in and consent to scopes needed for application
  pca
    .getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters)
    .then((response) => {
      res.redirect(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
});
```

The response I am getting is

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationFailed",
        "message": "Authentication failed."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "**AuthenticationFailed**" usually occurs if you are using different scope token to call the API.

***I tried to generate access token with the same scope as you
via Postman and got the same error while calling the query like below:***

[image]

Please **note** that,

- **`user.read`** audience is Microsoft Graph API
- **`https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation`** audience is Azure Service Management.

As you have given two different scopes with different audiences, it will consider the first scope (`user.read`) to generate the token as mentioned in this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72814042/azure-msal-brower-with-nextjs-passing-only-one-scope-to-the-api/72866562#72866562) which was solved by me.

When you call the query **`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01`** with the above token, you will get the error as it is intended for MS Graph audience.

I tried to generate the token with scope **`https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation`** only, removing **`user.read`** like below:

[image]

**With the above generated token, I am able to call the API successfully like below:**

[image]

If you want token with different scopes, then you have to generate two access tokens separately.